# Error al importar y usar los formularios de Flask

Tags: python, formularios, flask

Estoy usando los formularios de Flask

instale la libreria

```
pip install Flask-WTF
```

y luego en un archivo que lo llame form.py esta la siguiente informacion

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm 
from wtforms import StringField, TextField
from wtforms.fields.html import EmailField
```

sin embargo me subraya las palabras flask_wtf, wtforms y wtforms.fields.html5, lanzandome el error 'Import "flask_wtf" could not be resolvedPylance'

Answer (score 0):

Tendrías que mostrar mas a detalle la parte del código y como lo estas usando, pero
pienso que puedes haber instalado la librería en otra carpeta distinta a la del proyecto, lo cual me pasaba mucho por que lo hacia directo al CMD... Comprueba si tienes la librería en la CARPETA DEL PROYECTO. Puedes escribir

pip freeze > requirements.txt en la consola de la carpeta y automaticamente creara un archivo txt con todas las librerías que estas usando.

Saludos